# creating a local MongoDB replica set based on a single database on MongoHQ

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

We have a single mongo database hosted on MongoHQ.

We now want to move to a replica-set on our own servers. I was hoping I could change the current db to a replica set, and then add our servers to it, and then eventually remove the mongohq instance from the set.

is this possible/appropriate with mongohq? is it better to do a mongodump?

what is the best way of going from single production mongohq db to a replicaset on our own servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, since this is a single instance, it would require some help from the MongoHQ team. Depending on the size of the database, we can assist. However, if the data is small enough (2GB or less), it would end up being much faster to just move it with a copy or a mongodump/mongorestore.

Also, MongoHQ has replica set plans as well. It is easy to add redundancy and high-availability this way.

Hope this helps!

Jason
MongoHQ

Comment: the data is still very small - i'll probably do a dump/restore. would i create the local replica set before doing the restore locally? or do i do the restore and then configure the replica set?

Comment: Create the replica set first, making sure that it is up and running and that you can connect to it normally. Then, run the mongorestore of the data to the new replica set. From there, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported by MongoHQ b/c you ultimately have to start the `mongod` process with a `--replSet <replica set name>` flag. If you want to create your own replica set, I would get a dump of your data from HQ and then go from there creating your own set where you are in control of all nodes.